# Using jQuery to select checkboxes with click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to use jquery to select all checkboxes on a page that have an associated click event? I considered adding a class, for instance HasClickEvent, that I could use to identify such classes, but I am editing a huge script where click events are sporadically added all over the place and I think this would probably end up being messier, so a single jQuery call would be perfect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery.each($('input[type=checkbox]').data('events'), function(i, event){

    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){

        if(handler.type.toString() == 'click')
        {
            // do something
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, do you know what toString() will return in the case of no associated event?

Comment: This checks the events that have been bound, so in case of no bound event, this wont be running. By the way, this is good solution.

Answer (score 2):

To check all

```
$('.checkbox').attr('checked','checked'); // checkbox is the class for all checboxes to be selected change it with our own
```

To deselect all

```
$('.checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google reveals [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/eventbound), but it's pretty old. You may be able to read the code and see how they are achieving it though :D

Answer (score 0):

If the `click` events are attached using the `onclick` attribute (instead of added dynamically via JavaScript/jQuery), you can do it like this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][onclick]").each(function() {
    //All returned elements have an onclick attribute
});
```